# Kentico Azure Search - Auto Rebuild Task Failure

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I have setup Azure search on my Kentico site. The search works fine.

When I try to setup automatic index build it fails.

[image]

[image]

So, it's never rebuilding the indexes. How can I fix this issues?

Comment: Do you have some customization on your azure search fields?

Comment: @A.vanHugten No, I do not have any customization

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that either there are two columns with the same name *or* perhaps the case of a column name has changed somehow and Azure is struggling with that. I'd suggest dropping the index in the Azure portal and seeing if the automatic indexing will recreate it.

If you can go into the portal, it's worth checking the index definition to confirm that the fields are as you expect.